# Yii2 Redirect after Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, authentication, yii2

I done a facebook login to my application,which helps the register user can login their account by using their facebook.
I was planning to redirect the loged user to their my account page instead of getting back to Index page.How can I achieve this.
**My controller**

```
    public function successCallback($client)
    {
        $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
        // user login or signup comes here
       // print_r($attributes['email']);die();
        $user_email = $attributes['email'];  
        $user = User::find()->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->one();
        $count = count($user);
if($count == 0){
return $this->redirect['user/register']
    }  else{
//auto login function
}
```

How can I achieve auto login??
Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For autologin, you can use either [switchIdentity](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#switchIdentity()-detail) ou [login](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail) method. Besides internal logs, there is no difference between them.

```
if($count == 0){
    return $this->redirect['user/register']
}  else{
    Yii::$app->user->switchIdentity($user);
    // or Yii::$app->user->login($user);

    return $this->redirect(['controller/action']);
}
```